# Starting a multi-node cluster with Docker Compose - where do you configure host actual names?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to run an Elasticsearch cluster with docker.
I have 3 machines with IP addresses ip1,ip2,ip3 and I want to run the cluster using them.

Inside [Elasticsearch site,](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-compose-file) they provide the following docker compose file:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.1
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.1
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.1
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

so how do I configure the 3 machines I have in this docker-compose file? under node.name? like a full URL of the machine? the IP address? something else?

Do I need to run 'docker-compose up' in all of the machines?
The machines reside in the same local network, and all have docker daemon running.

Comment: You could run `docker-compose up` with what you already have and check which are the container names. Since they are in the same network, they will be able to talk to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to run 'docker-compose up' in all of the machines? The
> machines reside in the same local network, and all have docker daemon
> running.

All these elasticsearch nodes will be just containers on the same Docker host, so if you do that you'll have a total of 9 containers on these 3 machines.

To spread these three containers across multiple machines you need to set up your machines into Docker Swarm and prepare docker-compose file, which is eligible for `docker stack` command. Then you deploy the docker-compose file from the manager.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/

Comment: Micahl - i don't have 'docker-machine' installed on my machines, it it mandatory?

Comment: @nadavgam it's not mandatory. Follow these instructions to initialize the docker swarm on the first machine: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/create-swarm/ and then join others to the swarm by using the command which will be returned from `docker swarm init` this step is described here https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/add-nodes/

Comment: thats what i did, and 'docker node ls' shows the two nodes, but i dont think anything is running. 'docker container ps' shows nothing...

Comment: docker stack services vossibility
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                                                                             PORTS
rfcppcod0xmv        vossibility_es02    replicated          0/1                 ger-registry.caas.mycom.com/hpc-middleware/docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:latest   
stzsspyyore1        vossibility_es01    replicated          0/1                 ger-registry.caas.mycom.com/hpc/docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:latest   *:9200->9200/tcp

Comment: @nadavgam `replicated 0/1` suggests that the `docker stack` command worked, but containers struggle to start, maybe they are exiting early due to some error. Could you try `docker ps -a`?

Comment: 0070af178d5c        37190fe5beea        "/tini -- /usr/local…"   6 hours ago         Exited (2) 6 hours ago                               fervent_keller
6fb8725192ea        37190fe5beea        "/tini -- /usr/local…"   6 hours ago         Exited (2) 6 hours ago                               interesting_kepler
846e5782cc4c        37190fe5beea        "/tini -- /usr/local…"   6 hours ago         Exited (2) 6 hours ago                               lucid_perlman
1532923f3636        adfab5632ef4        "/usr/local/bin/kiba…"   7 hours ago         Exited (

Comment: oh i 'docker service ps <service name>' and it shows that it fails because "no such image", but I'm using image that i see in 'docker image ls' list...its an image i pulled before